# Save open excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

How do I save an open excel file using python= I currently read the excel workbook using XLRD but I need to save the excel file so any changes the user inputs are read.

I have done this using a VBA script from within excel which saves the workbook every x seconds, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using xlwt?

- for Python 2 -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt/0.7.4
- for Python 3 -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt3/0.1.2

Answer (score 0):

It looks like XLRD is used for reading the data, not interfacing with excel. So no, unless you use a different library using python is not the best way to do this, what is wrong with the VBA script?

Comment: Hi, as well as saving the excel file I'm also reading and writing to it using an external data feed. Using a VBA script I see the 'save as' dialog box sometimes when I assume the data feed is writing/reading from as such the data feed stops until the user closes the dialog box.

Comment: Ah, well then I do not know.

Comment: im trying the Application.DisplayAlerts = False command in the vba autosave script to see if that fixes it. you have to let it run for a few hours to tell...